# How to render ejs page (containing angularjs) in nodejs

Tags: html, angularjs, node.js

I have following code for ejs page, a script and a nodejs script. When I execute ejs page independently, it works fine, however the same page fails to load when rendered via nodejs. Please assist

ejs page:

'

```
<html>
<script src="/home/aniruddha/Downloads/angular.js"></script>
<script src="/home/aniruddha/NodeJS/script.js"></script>
<Title>AngularJS and NodeJS in action </Title>
<body ng-app="Main">
 <div ng-controller="Display">
   {{message}}
 </div>
</body>
</html>

script:
var mod=angular.module("Main",[]);
var cntrolr=function($scope) { $scope.message="This is from AngularJS!!"; };
mod.controller("Display",cntrolr);
```

nodejs script:

```
var express=require('express');
var path=require('path');
var app=express();
//var ang=require('angular');
app.set('view engine','ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname,'views'));
app.get('/', function (req,res) { res.render('index');});
app.listen(8080,function(){ console.log('Listening on port 8080');}); '
```

When I load the page with above mentioned nodejs script, page returns with variable name but not the value

Comment: Are `/home/aniruddha/Downloads/angular.js` these files loaded correctly

Comment: Yes! Page works fine if I load it manually.

Comment: Check console to find out the error i guess that will give idea to resolve this

Comment: I did, console is blank :(

Comment: I just found one error "GET 
http://localhost:8080/home/aniruddha/NodeJS/views/angular.js"   [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 1ms]

Comment: Why isn't it found whereas it is still present there?

Answer (score 0):

**To render ejs page (containing angularjs files) in nodejs**

Install Angular Universal  in angular, which enables server-side rendering.

```
npm ng@angular-Universal.
```

You can find the complete step by step process in digital Ocean.
Following is the complete Tutorial for installing angular-Universal
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-angular-universal.

Please follow the steps below:

1. npm init @angular myApp
2. ng add @nguniversal/express-engine or npm install @nguniversal/express-engine --legacy-peer-deps
3. Update the generated file `server.ts`, which generated as a result of installing angular Universal

```
import 'zone.js/node';

import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
import * as express from 'express';
import { existsSync } from 'node:fs';
import { join } from 'node:path';
import { AppServerModule } from './src/main.server';
import * as ejs from 'ejs'
import * as ejsLayouts from 'express-ejs-layouts'
import * as path from 'node:path';



// The Express app is exported so that it can be used by serverless Functions.
export function app(): express.Express {
  const server = express();
  const distFolder = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/appname/browser');
  const indexHtml = existsSync(join(distFolder, 'indus.original.ejs')) ? 'index.original.ejs' : 'index';
  server.use(ejsLayouts)
  server.set('layout','indus')
  // Our Universal express-engine (found @ https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/main/modules/express-engine)
  server.engine('ejs', ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: AppServerModule
  }));

  server.set('view engine', 'ejs');
  server.set('views', distFolder);

  // Example Express Rest API endpoints
  // server.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
  // Serve static files from /browser
  server.get('*.*', express.static(distFolder, {
    maxAge: '1y'
  }));
  var template = path.resolve('.../YourAppName/dist/app/browser/', 'indus.ejs');

  // All regular routes use the Universal engine
  server.get('/', (req, res) => {
    ejs.renderFile(template, { req, providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl }] }, function (err, tem) {
      if (err) {
          throw err;
      } else {
          res.end(tem);
  }});
  });

  return server;
}

function run(): void {
  const port = process.env['PORT'] || 5000;

  // Start up the Node server
  const server = app();
  server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
}

// Webpack will replace 'require' with '__webpack_require__'
// '__non_webpack_require__' is a proxy to Node 'require'
// The below code is to ensure that the server is run only when not requiring the bundle.
declare const __non_webpack_require__: NodeRequire;
const mainModule = __non_webpack_require__.main;
const moduleFilename = mainModule && mainModule.filename || '';
if (moduleFilename === __filename || moduleFilename.includes('iisnode')) {
  run();
}

export * from './src/main.server';
```

Above is the updated `server.ts` file
Update the varible template in the above file by replacing your app's path

4. npm run build:ssr
5. npm run serve:ssr

   check the app running on the corresponding port, which should be specified in your terminal
6. npm i @types/'*moudles*'

...  You Can type the module name like as follows:

npm i @types/ejs

```
   and
```

npm i @types/express-ejs-layouts

7. npm i '*modules*'

...  You Can type the module name like as follows:

npm i ejs

and

npm i express-ejs-layouts

8. npm add html-loader
9. npm i bootstrap
10. Create `typings.d.ts`, add the following code in it:

declare module '*ejs'
{
const value:string;
export default value
}

11. Create ejs file for the component you wish to use, example `comp.component.ejs`, in this file you can use both html and js together.
    Then reference the file in the `app.component.ts` file like as follows:

import *as require from 'html-loader!./comp.component.ejs'
export class appComponent{

```
html-Loader:any
constructor() {
  this.html-Loader = require;
     this.html-Loader = this.test.default;
}
```

}

12. Once all the steps are followed, you will have to build again the app using the command: npm run build:ssr
13. And then npm run serve:ssr

** Please don't miss to update variable distFolder with your app's name and specify your app's path in the template variable of server.ts file **

Navigate to the url, the one shown in the terminal and you can see your Angular app with ejs working absolutely fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).